# SRAI code not redirecting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aiml

Just beginning with AIML and can't seem to get the `<srai>` command to work for linking synonyms. I'm using Ruby on Rails and the Programr gem. For example, here is my code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<aiml version="1.0">

<category>
    <pattern>HELLO</pattern>
    <template>Hi there!</template>
</category>
<category>
    <pattern>HI</pattern>
    <template><srai>HELLO</srai></template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

And when I type Hi, my chat bot does not understand what I'm talking about. In the command logs, you can see it's querying for "Hi", instead of "Hello". Any idea where I might be steering wrong?

For added reference, here is my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def ask_warwick
    reaction = WARWICK.get_reaction(params[:query])
    render json: { response: reaction.present? ? reaction : 'I do not understand' }
  end
end
```

And my initializer:

```
require 'programr'

brains = Dir.glob("lib/warwick/*")

WARWICK = ProgramR::Facade.new
WARWICK.learn(brains)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an error in the gem code

go into the gem and find the file lib/programr/aiml_parser.rb

then comment out the line around 193 where it says  currentSrai = Srai.new

```
  @parser.listen(:characters, %w{ srai }){|text|
    # currentSrai = Srai.new 
    currentSrai.add(text)
  }
```